# Php code prints nothing while using with a HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the problem with my code?

```
$sql = "select username,num from login order by num desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rnk=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $row["username"];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row["num"];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $rnk;
        echo "</td></tr>"
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results found";
}
$conn->close();
```

I had placed the above code after providing necessary connection codes between table element in my html page with .php extension. When i call the page it shows only a blank page. Its not even showing the table headers.

Comment: Tyyypooooooooo:) `echo "</td></tr>"`

Comment: even
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["num"]. " " . $rnk. "</td></tr>";

doesnt works

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky is trying to say that you forgot `;` on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$sql = "select username,num from login order by num desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rnk=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "<tr><td>".($row['username'])."</td>";
 echo "<td>".($row['num'])."</td>";
 echo "<td>".($rnk)."</td></tr>";
 }

    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results found";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Crank up PHP error reporting so you can see what the real problem is.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Also look in the Apache `error.log` to see what, if any, errors are being logged. Assuming you are using Apache